# knockoutjs - select change event doesn't fire the first time

Tags: knockout.js

I have a problem with one `select` element. I create a binding for the `change` event, and it works when I change the selected element manually, but if the select element is binding with a specified value, the change function is not call.

My html is like this:

```html
<select data-bind="value: myfield, event:{change:myfunction}">
    <option value="">Select an element</option>
    <option value="1">Element 1</option>
    <option value="2">Element 2</option>
</select>
```

I need it so that if the property myfield has a value different to '' the change function will execute.

If I choose an element the myfunction is call and all it´s ok, but when the page is load, and for example myfield has the value "1" the function is not call, and I need that this function will be execute, I hope that you can undertand my problem.

Comment: I am trying to understand your problem. Can you explain this part of your question, can you give some details? "but if the select element is binding with a specified value"

Comment: Thanks friend, look, if I choose an element the myfunction is call and all it´s ok, but when the page is load, and for example myfield has the value "1" the function is not call, and I need that this function will be execute, I hope that you can undertand my problem.

Answer (score 24):

You're having trouble because you're *fighting* Knockout, not *using* it here :-). You should read through [the `selectedOptions` documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html) and [`options` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html), or perhaps even do some of the [KO tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/).

Basically, you *never* want to handle the `change` event for DOM elements yourself. Knockout is meant to do exactly that: update your ViewModel when the DOM inputs change. In addition, Knockout should also be in charge of generating the `option`s for you.

Your html should look something like this:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.availableOptions = [1, 2];
    self.myfield = ko.observable();

    self.myfield.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        // Handle a change here, e.g. update something on the server with Ajax.
        alert('myfield changed to ' + newValue);
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: availableOptions,
                       value: myfield,
                       optionsCaption: 'Select an element'">
</select>
```

If you actually *need* to subscribe to a change in the dropdown, subscribe to the `myfield` changes instead as shown above.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, you are right, I'm no using ko so good, but now I cannot do so many changes to do a good binding (talk with the PM :)), so for this reason I need to do a "fix", maybe you have any idea?

Comment: The easiest way to fix this is to use KO correctly. Any other solution will be much more work IMO.

Comment: @JulitoAvellaneda From what I read, the `self.myfield.subscribe` function exactly does what you need: get notified of any changes to the field value, whether those changes result from an actual change event, or from knockout's internal magic. It's also not a drastic change to your existing code.